# Install Ubuntu on Hardware Raid 1 server , message partition disk

Tags: ubuntu, installation, partitioning, raid

The installer has detected that the following disks have mounted partitions:

/dev/sda/

Do you want the installer to try and unmount the partitions on these disks 
before continuing? If you leave them mounted, you will not be able to create, 
delete, or resize partitions on these disks, but you may be able to install 
to existing partitions there.

But there is problem , RAID 1 logical drive 1 , Diskname is /dev/sda

What will happen if I choose "yes"?